# Express-validator middleware either times out, is not able to read req.params, or complains about being a promise instead of a call back function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am using express-validator for an Express backend application. I have used the validator in some routes already, but in this case, I am trying to make a DB call and based on a value returning a specific set of validation rules.

Router:

```
const { checkValidation, validateCreateGame, validateStartGame } = require("../middleware/validateRequestBody");

router.post("/create", verifyAdminToken, validateCreateGame(), checkValidation, async (req, res) => {
    ... 
}

router.post("/:gameId/start", verifyAdminToken, validateStartGame(), checkValidation, async (req, res) => {
    ...
}
```

validateRequestBody.js :

```
const validateCreateGame = (req, res, next) => {
    return [
        body("name").notEmpty().isString().trim().escape(),
        body("description").notEmpty().isString().trim().escape(),
        body("type").notEmpty().isInt(),
    ];
};

const validateStartGame = async (req, res, next) => {
    const Game = new GameModel();
    const game = await Game.findOne({ id: req.params.gameId });
    switch (game.type) {
        case "TYPE1":
            return [
                body("duration").notEmpty().isInt(),
                body("points").exists().isArray(),
                ...
            ];
        ...
    }
};

const checkValidation = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res
            .status(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST)
            .json({ error: "the required information was not provided for this request" });
    }
    next();
};
```

The verifyAdminToken is another middleware which authenticates the JWT passed in. That is working fine.

The expectation from the validateStartGame middleware was to fetch the Game Type from the DB (the GameModel part of the code works fine, and I am able to get a valid game object from the DB), and then based on the type, return a list of rules, as each game type would require different inputs.

The validateCreateGame middleware also works as expected. So I tried replicated the functionality, i.e., returned a list of validator rules.

I am open to any suggestions on how best to handle this!

I have tried calling the validateStartGame as `validateStartGame` and `validateStartGame()`. I have also tried using a `.then()` instead of an `async/await`.

I was hoping that one of these combinations would fix this error.

Comment: Think about when you're _calling_ your "middleware", and with what.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code has multiple points that could lead to a problem and you did not provide enough information to debug the problem. It would help if there is a minimal reproducible example and some error stack trace.

Some issues I am seeing at the moment:

1. Middleware needs to be a callback, thus it should be validateStartGame instead of validateStartGame()
2. Middleware not calling next(). For example, validateCreateGame
3. Mixing sanity check with business logic check

Point 3 is just a coding style suggestion but I would recommend performing sanity check before business logic check